# Using std::ostream as a class member

Tags: c++, ostream

I'm working on a simple progress indicator class, and I have a question about using a `std::ostream` object as a class member. The following example compiles and runs correctly on OS X and Linux.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct ProgressIndicator {

public:
    ProgressIndicator(unsigned int update_interval, std::string message,
                      std::ostream& outstream = std::cerr)
        : update_interval(update_interval), message(message),
          stream(outstream.rdbuf()), _counter(0), _interval(update_interval)
    {
    }

    void increment(unsigned int by = 1)
    {
        _counter += by;
        if(_counter >= _interval) {
            stream << message << _counter << std::endl;
            _interval += update_interval;
        }
    }

    unsigned int get_count()
    {
        return _counter;
    }

protected:
    unsigned int update_interval;
    std::string message;
    std::ostream stream;

private:
    unsigned long _counter;
    unsigned long _interval;

};

int main()
{
    ProgressIndicator p1(5, "progress <stdout> ", std::cout);
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        p1.increment();
    }

    ProgressIndicator p2(5, "progress <stderr> ", std::cerr);
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        p2.increment();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that `std::ostream` objects cannot be copied, and must be passed by reference. But I don't understand why initializing with `stream(outstream)` doesn't work, and why I had to resort to the `rdbuf()` hack. Is there no "better", more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: You understand that they cannot be copied, but don't understand why trying to copy one, doesn't work? I am confused..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are still copying the `std::ostream`. Even though the constructor isn't copying the parameter, it still needs to copy the object into `ProgressIndicator::stream` somehow.

One way to solve your problem would be to store a reference to the stream, though this only works if you know the stream object will outlast your class instance:

```
struct ProgressIndicator {
    ProgressIndicator(std::ostream& outstream = std::cerr /* ... */)
      : stream(outstream) /* ... */ {}
    // ...

protected:
    std::ostream& stream;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Ugh, silly mistake on my part. I intended the class member to store an ostream reference, but did not properly specify it. That was it.